# About the union of discrete subsets in $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Problem:
I've to give an example of two discrete subsets A,B ⊂ $\Bbb R$ such that A∪B it's not discrete.
I've thinking about $\Bbb N$ and *P*={1,
$\frac{1}{2}$,..., $\frac{1}{n}$} but $\Bbb N$∪*P* is discrete.
How could I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Instead of stopping $P$ at some arbitrary $n$, what if you keeping going?

Comment: the end will be 0 ?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get it

Comment: How about $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb N\}$?

Comment: but 0 is not an isolated point therefore {0} can be discrete

Comment: I mean *can't..

Comment: @JacobSchwartz The hangup may be on the definition of discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  The set $\{0\}$ is discrete in $\mathbb{R}$ because its only point, $0$, has a neighborhood $U$--any open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains $\{0\}$ works--such that $U \cap \{0\} = \{0\}$.

Comment: you're right @FabioSomenzi